# How to implement and use HTTP/2 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http2

I have a node.js app. I was using http for creating server as shown below:

...

```
   var http=require('http');

   var server=http.createServer(app);
```

...

And this works perfectly.

Then I implemented http/2 module from npm as shown below :

```
npm install http2
```

And I have the package now. Then I changed my code as:

```
var http2 = require('http2') ;
var server= http2.createServer(app);
```

But this doesn't work. I get "could not get any response" error from postman. 
Why doesn't it work and how can I fix it and use http2?

**EDIT** : I found HTTP/2 documentation. You can see how you can implement HTTP/2, what you should do for server side, what you should do for client side and other informations about http2 in this document. Also I found out that to check http2 with browsers, you need to generate the certificate and key in this document. **The document:**

https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example

Comment: "Then I implemented http/2 module from npm": Don't! https://www.npmjs.com/package/http2 says "This package has been deprecated
Author message:

Use the built-in module in node 9.0.0 or newer, instead"

Comment: You don't seem to have followed the documentation at all: https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example

Comment: You haven't defined the app variable.

Comment: No I defined. Normal http works perfectly. But http2 does not work.

Comment: "EDIT : I searched and found HTTP/2 documentation" — I posted that exact link in a comment 21 hours ago!

Comment: I can't vote your comment but if you write it as an answer, I can tick it as a true answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Postman does not support HTTP/2.

Source: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2701

Comment: @MinelAydın — as [the documentation says](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example) browsers don't support unencrypted HTTP/2

Comment: So how can I use http2? Or how can I make it encrypted, what should I do?

Comment: @MinelAydın — Follow the instructions in the documentation.

Comment: Where will I write this? To generate the certificate and key for this example, run: 

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj '/CN=localhost' \
  -keyout localhost-privkey.pem -out

Comment: On the command line. https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/openssl-quick-reference-guide.htm